# Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table as follows:

```
Filename - varchar
Creation Date - Date format dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
Oldest cdr date - Date format dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
```

How can I calcuate the difference in hours minutes and seconds (and possibly days) between the two dates in Oracle SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322935/subtracting-dates-in-oracle-number-or-interval-datatype

Answer (score 140):

You can substract dates in Oracle. This will give you the difference in days. Multiply by 24 to get hours, and so on.

```
SQL> select oldest - creation from my_table;
```

If your date is stored as character data, you have to convert it to a date type first.

```
SQL> select 24 * (to_date('2009-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
             - to_date('2009-07-07 19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_hours 
       from dual;

DIFF_HOURS
----------
       2.5
```

---

*Note*:

This answer applies to dates represented by the Oracle data type `DATE`.
Oracle also has a data type `TIMESTAMP`, which can also represent a date (with time). If you subtract `TIMESTAMP` values, you get an `INTERVAL`; to extract numeric values, use the `EXTRACT` function.

Comment: Has there been a change in Oracle's behavior at some point?  When I subtract one date from another I get an `INTERVAL` data type, not a simple float.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: No, when you subtract values of type `DATE`, you get the number of days (as a `NUMBER`). However, if you subtract `TIMESTAMP` values, you get `INTERVALDS`. Probably you are working with `TIMESTAMP` and not `DATE` values. I edited the answer.

Comment: Regarding your note - Both the `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types have a time (hours, minutes and seconds) component. `TIMESTAMP` also has a fractional seconds time component (and potentially time zone components).

Comment: "This will give you the difference in days." Can you link to Oracle documentation please?

Answer (score 26):

To get result in seconds:

```
select (END_DT - START_DT)*60*60*24 from MY_TABLE;
```

Check [https://community.oracle.com/thread/2145099?tstart=0][1]

Answer (score 19):

```
select 
    extract( day from diff ) Days, 
    extract( hour from diff ) Hours, 
    extract( minute from diff ) Minutes 
from (
        select (CAST(creationdate as timestamp) - CAST(oldcreationdate as timestamp)) diff   
        from [TableName] 
     );
```

This will give you three columns as Days, Hours and Minutes.

Answer (score 16):

```
declare
strTime1 varchar2(50) := '02/08/2013 01:09:42 PM';
strTime2 varchar2(50) := '02/08/2013 11:09:00 PM';
v_date1 date := to_date(strTime1,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM');
v_date2 date := to_date(strTime2,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM');
difrence_In_Hours number;
difrence_In_minutes number;
difrence_In_seconds number;
begin
    difrence_In_Hours   := (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24;
    difrence_In_minutes := difrence_In_Hours * 60;
    difrence_In_seconds := difrence_In_minutes * 60;

    dbms_output.put_line(strTime1);        
    dbms_output.put_line(strTime2);
    dbms_output.put_line('*******');
    dbms_output.put_line('difrence_In_Hours  : ' || difrence_In_Hours);
    dbms_output.put_line('difrence_In_minutes: ' || difrence_In_minutes);
    dbms_output.put_line('difrence_In_seconds: ' || difrence_In_seconds);        
end ;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

You may also try this:

```
select to_char(to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+(end_date - start_date),'hh24:mi:ss')
       as run_time from some_table;
```

It displays time in more human readable form, like: 00:01:34.
If you need also days you may simply add DD to last formatting string.

Answer (score 7):

Calculate age from HIREDATE to system date of your computer

```
SELECT HIREDATE||'        '||SYSDATE||'       ' ||
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,HIREDATE)/12) ||' YEARS '||
TRUNC((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,HIREDATE))-(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,HIREDATE)/12)*12))||
'MONTHS' AS "AGE  "  FROM EMP;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use to_timestamp function to convert the dates to timestamps and perform a substract operation.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP ('13.10.1990 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  - 
TO_TIMESTAMP ('01.01.1990:00:10:00','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: I have tried both the to_date and to_timestamp and both give me an answer in days, rounded down so if the difference is 1 hour I receive an answer of 0, multiplying this by 24 gives 0.  I do receive the correct answer if I type in the date time but I can't do this for 25m rows.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Using a substraction between timestamps it would return you another timestamp in a format like "DAYS HOUR:MINS:SECS.milisecs". You could trunc this to get the value you need

Comment: Subtraction between timestamps returns an INTERVAL datatype. You can use the EXTRACT function to return various parts of an interval
eg
select extract(hour from (timestamp '2009-12-31 14:00:00' - timestamp '2009-12-31 12:15:00')) hr from dual;
Note: That only shows the HOUR part, so if the difference is 1 day and 1 hour, this will show 1 not 25.

Answer (score 4):

In oracle 11g

```
SELECT end_date - start_date AS day_diff FROM tablexxx
suppose the starT_date end_date is define in the tablexxx
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select days||' '|| time from (
SELECT to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
    (CLOSED_DATE - CREATED_DATE), 'J') - 1)  days,
   to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') +
      (CLOSED_DATE - CREATED_DATE), 'HH24:MI:SS') time
 FROM  request  where REQUEST_ID=158761088 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that looks a bit simpler, try this for finding events in a table which occurred in the past 1 minute:

With this entry you can fiddle with the decimal values till you get the minute value that you want. The value .0007 happens to be 1 minute as far as the sysdate significant digits are concerned. You can use multiples of that to get any other value that you want:

```
select (sysdate - (sysdate - .0007)) * 1440 from dual;
```

Result is 1 (minute)

Then it is a simple matter to check for

```
select * from my_table where (sysdate - transdate) < .00071;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you select two dates from '***your_table***' and want too see the result as a single column output (eg. '**days - hh:mm:ss**')  you could use something like this.
First you could calculate the interval between these two dates and after that export all the data you need from that interval:

```
         select     extract (day from numtodsinterval (second_date
                                                   - add_months (created_date,
                                                                 floor (months_between (second_date,created_date))),
                                                   'day'))
             || ' days - '
             || extract (hour from numtodsinterval (second_date
                                                    - add_months (created_date,
                                                                  floor (months_between (second_date,created_date))),
                                                    'day'))
             || ':'
             || extract (minute from numtodsinterval (second_date
                                                      - add_months (created_date,
                                                                    floor (months_between (second_date, created_date))),
                                                      'day'))
             || ':'
             || extract (second from numtodsinterval (second_date
                                                      - add_months (created_date,
                                                                    floor (months_between (second_date, created_date))),
                                                      'day'))
     from    your_table
```

And that should give you result like this:
         **0 days - 1:14:55**

Answer (score 1):

```
select (floor(((DATE2-DATE1)*24*60*60)/3600)|| ' : ' ||floor((((DATE2-DATE1)*24*60*60) -floor(((DATE2-DATE1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)|| '  ' ) as time_difference from TABLE1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_2, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))*60*60*24 sum_seconds,
         (TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_2, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))*60*24 sum_minutes,
         (TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_2, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))*24 sum_hours,
         (TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE(:P_comapre_date_2, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')) sum_days
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want get date defer from using table and column.

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME_1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') - 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME_2, 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD')  AS DATEDIFF       
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Why do you convert the dates to ISO strings only to immediately convert them back to dates? That's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(actual_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') start_time,
to_char(actual_completion_date,'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') end_time,
floor((actual_completion_date-actual_start_date)*24*60)||'.'||round(mod((actual_completion_date-actual_start_date)*24*60*60,60)) diff_time
from fnd_concurrent_requests 
order by request_id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count time between to dates:

```
SELECT
  (TO_CHAR( TRUNC (ROUND(((sysdate+1) - sysdate)*24,2))*60,'999999')
  +
  TO_CHAR(((((sysdate+1)-sysdate)*24)- TRUNC(ROUND(((sysdate+1) - sysdate)*24,2)))/100*60 *100, '09'))/60
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
with tbl_demo AS
    (SELECT TO_DATE('11/26/2013 13:18:50', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt1
   , TO_DATE('11/28/2013 21:59:12', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt2 
     FROM dual)
SELECT dt1
     , dt2
     , round(dt2 - dt1,2) diff_days
     , round(dt2 - dt1,2)*24 diff_hrs
     , numtodsinterval((dt2 - dt1),'day') diff_dd_hh_mm_ss
  from tbl_demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

select round( (tbl.Todate - tbl.fromDate) * 24 * 60 * 60 )
from table tbl

Answer (score 0):

for oracle sql I justbn did this and works perfect :

```
SELECT trunc(date_col_1) -  trunc(date_col_2) 
FROM   TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select
  2    numtodsinterval(
  3      to_date('2024-05-04 03:02:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date('2024-05-03 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  4      , 'DAY') as diff_interval
  5  from dual
  6  ;

DIFF_INTERVAL
---------------------------------------
+000000001 03:02:01.000000000

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="select bsp_bp,user_name,status,
to_char(ins_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh12:mi:ss AM'),
to_char(pickup_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh12:mi:ss AM'),
trunc((pickup_date-ins_date)*24*60*60,2),message,status_message 
from valid_bsp_req where id >= '$id'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Single query that will return time difference of two timestamp columns:

```
select INS_TS, MAIL_SENT_TS, extract( hour from (INS_TS - MAIL_SENT_TS) ) timeDiff 
from MAIL_NOTIFICATIONS;
```