# ORACLE calculate hours between two timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

so i am creating a database for an airline as part of my university coursework. first time using oracle.

I am trying to calculate the hours between two timestamps.

so something like

```
v_interval = new.departure_time - v_arrival_time;
v_days = extract (day . v_interval);
v_hours = extract (hours, v_interval) + (v_days * 24);
```

how do you guys think i should do it?

Answer (score -1):

Similar question:

- [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

More examples:

- [Date / Time Arithmetic with Oracle 9/10](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html)