# Subtracting Dates in Oracle - Number or Interval Datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, oracle11g

I have a question about some of the internal workings for the Oracle DATE and INTERVAL datatypes. According to the [Oracle 11.2 SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#g196492), when you subtract 2 DATE datatypes, the result will be a NUMBER datatype.

On cursory testing, this appears to be true:

```
CREATE TABLE test (start_date DATE);
INSERT INTO test (start_date) VALUES (date'2004-08-08');
SELECT (SYSDATE - start_date) from test;
```

will return a NUMBER datatype.

But now if you do:

```
SELECT (SYSDATE - start_date) DAY(5) TO SECOND from test;
```

you get an INTERVAL datatype. In other words, Oracle can convert the NUMBER from the DATE subtraction into an INTERVAL type.

So now I figured I could try putting in a NUMBER datatype directly in the brackets (instead of doing 'SYSDATE - start_date' which results in a NUMBER anyways):

```
SELECT (1242.12423) DAY(5) TO SECOND from test;
```

But this results in the error:

```
ORA-30083: syntax error was found in interval value expression
```

So my question is: what's going on here? It seems like subtracting dates should lead to a NUMBER (as demonstrated in SELECT statement #1), which CANNOT be automatically cast to INTERVAL type (as demonstrated in SELECT statement #3). But Oracle seems to be able to do that somehow if you use the DATE subtraction expression instead of putting in a raw NUMBER (SELECT statement #2).

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen when you put instead of sysdate something like to_date('20120216', 'yyyymmdd') ?

Comment: Hi sorry, didn't see your comment until now :S.. First to answer your question, yes it does this even if it use 'to_date()' instead of SYSDATE. On another note though, I managed to figure out how DATE subtraction is stored so I posted it as my answer :D.. since no one else on the internet seems to have written about this yet, i figured i'd write up what I found out.

Comment: @BYS2 - Why would you put a number in () then try to subtract days from number and convert it to seconds: SELECT (1242.12423) DAY(5) TO SECOND from test? This is what you need to ask.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, I don't normally answer my own questions but after a bit of tinkering, I have figured out definitively how Oracle stores the result of a DATE subtraction.

When you subtract 2 dates, the value is not a NUMBER datatype (as the [Oracle 11.2 SQL Reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#g196492) would have you believe). The internal datatype number of a DATE subtraction is 14, which is a non-documented internal datatype (NUMBER is [internal datatype number 2](http://www.juliandyke.com/Internals/InternalDataTypes.html)). However, it is actually stored as 2 separate two's complement signed numbers, with the first 4 bytes used to represent the number of days and the last 4 bytes used to represent the number of seconds.

An example of a DATE subtraction resulting in a positive integer difference:

```
select date '2009-08-07' - date '2008-08-08' from dual;
```

Results in:

```
DATE'2009-08-07'-DATE'2008-08-08'
---------------------------------
                              364

select dump(date '2009-08-07' - date '2008-08-08') from dual;

DUMP(DATE'2009-08-07'-DATE'2008
-------------------------------
Typ=14 Len=8: 108,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Recall that the result is represented as a 2 seperate two's complement signed 4 byte numbers. Since there are no decimals in this case (364 days and 0 hours exactly), the last 4 bytes are all 0s and can be ignored. For the first 4 bytes, because my CPU has a little-endian architecture, the bytes are reversed and should be read as 1,108 or 0x16c, which is decimal 364.

An example of a DATE subtraction resulting in a negative integer difference:

```
select date '1000-08-07' - date '2008-08-08' from dual;
```

Results in:

```
DATE'1000-08-07'-DATE'2008-08-08'
---------------------------------
                          -368160

select dump(date '1000-08-07' - date '2008-08-08') from dual;

DUMP(DATE'1000-08-07'-DATE'2008-08-0
------------------------------------
Typ=14 Len=8: 224,97,250,255,0,0,0,0
```

Again, since I am using a little-endian machine, the bytes are reversed and should be read as 255,250,97,224 which corresponds to 11111111 11111010 01100001 11011111. Now since this is in two's complement signed binary numeral encoding, we know that the number is negative because the leftmost binary digit is a 1. To convert this into a decimal number we would have to reverse the 2's complement (subtract 1 then do the one's complement) resulting in: 00000000 00000101 10011110 00100000 which equals -368160 as suspected.

An example of a DATE subtraction resulting in a decimal difference:

```
select to_date('08/AUG/2004 14:00:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
 - to_date('08/AUG/2004 8:00:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_DATE('08/AUG/200414:00:00','DD/MON/YYYYHH24:MI:SS')-TO_DATE('08/AUG/20048:00:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                             .25
```

The difference between those 2 dates is 0.25 days or 6 hours.

```
select dump(to_date('08/AUG/2004 14:00:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 - to_date('08/AUG/2004 8:00:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) from dual;

DUMP(TO_DATE('08/AUG/200414:00:
-------------------------------
Typ=14 Len=8: 0,0,0,0,96,84,0,0
```

Now this time, since the difference is 0 days and 6 hours, it is expected that the first 4 bytes are 0. For the last 4 bytes, we can reverse them (because CPU is little-endian) and get 84,96 = 01010100 01100000 base 2 = 21600 in decimal. Converting 21600 seconds to hours gives you 6 hours which is the difference which we expected.

Hope this helps anyone who was wondering how a DATE subtraction is actually stored.

Comment: I try to avoid working with dates when possible, converting them to timestamps and storing/keeping the difference as intervals.

More verbose than the implicit/internal number type you see here, for sure. But it is more consistent and better documented.

Answer (score 10):

You get the syntax error because the date math does not return a NUMBER, but it returns an INTERVAL:

```
SQL> SELECT DUMP(SYSDATE - start_date) from test;

DUMP(SYSDATE-START_DATE)
-------------------------------------- 
Typ=14 Len=8: 188,10,0,0,223,65,1,0
```

You need to convert the number in your example into an INTERVAL first using the [NUMTODSINTERVAL Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm#i88258)

For example:

```
SQL> SELECT (SYSDATE - start_date) DAY(5) TO SECOND from test;

(SYSDATE-START_DATE)DAY(5)TOSECOND
----------------------------------
+02748 22:50:04.000000

SQL> SELECT (SYSDATE - start_date) from test;

(SYSDATE-START_DATE)
--------------------
           2748.9515

SQL> select NUMTODSINTERVAL(2748.9515, 'day') from dual;

NUMTODSINTERVAL(2748.9515,'DAY')
--------------------------------
+000002748 22:50:09.600000000

SQL>
```

Based on the reverse cast with the NUMTODSINTERVAL() function, it appears some rounding is lost in translation.

Comment: Ah, the extra 5 seconds is probably wall clock since SYSDATE was the point of reference. I would hazard a guess there was no rounding.

Comment: hmm thanks for your reply, but this is weird, because dump() function returned the type as '14'. But INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH is type 182 and DAY TO SECOND is type 183 (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci03typ.htm#421773)... Furthermore, if date subtraction really returns an interval then why does SQL*Plus display '2748.9515' when you subtracted the dates? and why does the official reference manual state that date subtraction results in a NUMBER?

Comment: DATE subtraction apparently produces a FLOAT. (Anyone have some really old Oracle docs that indicate this might have once been so?) Try `SELECT * FROM DBA_TYPES WHERE TYPE_OID = '0000000000000000000000000000000E'`. Also take a look at package SYS.STANDARD, where it looks like FLOAT is effectively the same as NUMBER (i.e. `subtype FLOAT is NUMBER`). Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis It is clear from the Oracle 11g DUMP() function that DATE subtraction returns Typ=14. Not much value in old docs. Google for Oracle Date Interval "Typ=14" and there is some talk of Type 14 that is not exactly documented anywhere.

Comment: I figured it out! :D. Read the solution I posted. thanks for the input though, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Subtracting one date from another results in a number; subtracting one timestamp from another results in an interval.
- Oracle converts timestamps to dates internally when performing timestamp arithmetic.
- Interval constants cannot be used in either date or timestamp arithmetic.

[Oracle 11gR2 SQL Reference Datetime Matrix](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#g196492)

Comment: Hey thanks for your input but see my answer.. Oracle documentation is actually incorrect/incomplete in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use extract() function to retrieve hour / minute / seconds from interval value. See below example, how to get hours from two timestamp columns. Hope this helps!

select INS_TS, MAIL_SENT_TS, extract( hour from (INS_TS - MAIL_SENT_TS) ) hourDiff from MAIL_NTFCTN;

Answer (score -5):

select TIMEDIFF (STR_TO_DATE('**07:15 PM**', '%h:%i %p') , STR_TO_DATE('**9:58 AM**', '%h:%i %p'))

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question, and isn't valid syntax for Oracle; did you miss the Oracle tags and references in the title and question?