# SQL to Oracle Date Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date

Currently in middle of migration from SQL Server to Oracle. Whats the best practices that i should applied across?

And we also encounter some problem like the dateadd functions not working in oracle.

MSSQL Code

```
USE [TEST]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_MONTHS_LAST_DAY](@MON int)
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS
BEGIN
RETURN DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,getdate())), DATEADD(m,-MON+1,datediff(dd,0,getdate()))) 
END
```

**Converted Oracle**

**create or replace**

```
FUNCTION GET_MONTHS_LAST_DAY
(
  v_MON IN NUMBER
)
RETURN DATE
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN utils.dateadd('DD', -utils.day_(utils.dateadd('M', 1, SYSDATE)), utils.dateadd('M', -v_MON + 1, utils.datediff('DD', 0, SYSDATE)));
END;
```

Any idea why i cannot compile the oracle functions? The only thing i see here is the dateadd functions are not available in oracle. Thanks.

Comment: Simple googling shows tons of samples with SQL Server's `DATEADD` counterpart in Oracle. [One of the samples](https://community.oracle.com/thread/514525?tstart=0) dating back to 2007 suggests that you use `INTERVAL` literal. [Official documentation on using `INTERVAL` literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221) from Database SQL Language Reference. I think this question has lots of duplicates, can cause discussions "the best practices that i should applied across", and thus should be closed in its current form unless you reword it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322935/subtracting-dates-in-oracle-number-or-interval-datatype

Comment: If you added the compile failure error message we might be able to help further.

Comment: It would be much easier to create the date for the following month and the subtract one which will give you the day before if you want to roll it yourself, but Oracle has a LAST_DAY function already: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/last_day.php

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks like Oracle SQL Developer automatic conversion script.

You need generate package utils. Yo can use button "generate utils package" ( 2nd button in capture)in util window.

[image: 2nd button Oracle SQL Developter]