# SQL filter query output based on difference of two timestamp field

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle db, I have a table where there are two columns of timestamp -

e.g. `record_insert_time` and `process_time` datatype is `DATE`, the format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss`

conceptually, `record_insert_time` is the time the record was inserted and `process_time` is the time when the record was processed.

I want to see all the records where, the difference between `record_insert_time` and `process_time` is greater than for example 200 seconds, how to write the where clause in this case ?

```
select * from p_data_process_table 
where process_time-record_insert_time >=100 
order by record_insert_time desc;
```

does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: You have the right logic, but check that dupe for how to calculate the difference.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9346340/2055998

Comment: thanks a lot, it did solve my problem, wonder why it did not show up in my searches.