# query to subtract date from systimestamp in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I want to perform a subtraction operation on the date returned from another query and the system time in oracle SQL. So far I have been able to use the result of another query but when I try to subtract from systimestamp it gives me the following error

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   '01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Below is my query

```
select round(to_number(systimestamp - e.last_time) * 24) as lag 
from (
   select ATTR_VALUE as last_time 
   from CONFIG 
   where ATTR_NAME='last_time' 
   and PROCESS_TYPE='new'
)  e;
```

I have also tried this

```
select to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)-e.last_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as lag 
from (
   select ATTR_VALUE as last_time 
   from CONFIG 
   where ATTR_NAME='last_time' 
     and PROCESS_TYPE='new'
)  e;
```

I want the difference between the time intervals to be in hours.

Thank you for any help in advance.

**P.S.** The datatype of ATTR_VALUE is VARCHAR2(150). A sample result of  `e.last_time` is `2016-09-05 22:43:81796`

Comment: What datatype is ATTR_VALUE?

Comment: @sers Okay so as I see, its VARCHAR2(150). That means I need to convert that to date

Comment: Why are you storing a `DATE` as a `VARCHAR`? Don't do that.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri check for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322935/subtracting-dates-in-oracle-number-or-interval-datatype

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  database schema is not designed by me and in the schema that column contains strings also so I guess the datatype is varchar and last_time is just one of the attributes in the table

Comment: @AkshayTilekar I already went through that page before I asked the question. Didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after lots of trial and errors I got this one

**1.** Turns out initially the error was because the data_type of `e.last_time` was `VARCHAR(150)`. 
   To find out the datatype of a given column in the table I used

```
desc <table_name>
```

which in my case was `desc CONFIG`

**2.** To convert VARCHAR to system time I have two options `to_timestamp` and `to_date`. If I use `to_timestamp` like

```
select round((systimestamp - to_timestamp(e.last_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSSSS')) * 24, 2) as lag 
from (
   select ATTR_VALUE as last_time 
   from CONFIG 
   where ATTR_NAME='last_time' 
   and PROCESS_TYPE='new'
)  e;
```

I get an error that round expects `NUMBER` and got `INTERVAL DAY TO SECONDS` since the difference in date comes out to be like `+41 13:55:20.663990`. To convert that into hour would require a complex logic.

An alternative is to use `to_data` which I preferred and used it as

```
select round((sysdate - to_date(e.last_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSSSS')) * 24, 2) as lag 
from (
   select ATTR_VALUE as last_time 
   from CONFIG 
   where ATTR_NAME='last_time' 
   and PROCESS_TYPE='new'
)  e;
```

This returns me the desired result i.e. the difference in hours rounded off to 2 floating digits

Comment: Unrelated, but: the derived table is useless here. You can do that with a plain select as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How do I update the statement then. I feel this is complicated

Comment: Hmmm, interesting date format you got there. `SSSSS` is the number of seconds since midnight. So it double counts the hours and minutes in the `HH24:MI` bit. Which doesn't much affect the outcome of your particular outcome but does show why this kind of soft-coded configuration tables are such a bad idea.

Comment: @APC As I said the schema is not designed by me and there is nothing I can do to improve it. And Yes it looks like a bad idea to me too.

Answer (score 1):

> "its VARCHAR2(150). That means I need to convert that to date"

`ATTR_VALUE` is a string so yes you need to convert it to the correct type before attempting to compare it with another datatype. Given your sample data the correct type would be timestamp, in which case your subquery should be:

```
(
   select to_timestamp(ATTR_VALUE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff5') as last_time 
   from CONFIG 
   where ATTR_NAME='last_time' 
     and PROCESS_TYPE='new'
)
```

The assumption is that your sample is representative of all the values in your CONFIG table for the given keys. If you have values in different formats your query will break on some other way: that's the danger of using this approach.

Comment: Well I used to_date now after I realised that my value was VARCHAR. Your query also results in the same thing. I get an interval day to seconds and need to convert that to hours. `+41 13:33:07.632492` is the result I get. I am not sure how to convert this to hours

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve this finally. See my answer, used `to_date` and `sysdate` instead of `to_timestamp` and `systimestamp`. Thank you for the help