# how to find the difference between time stamp in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have to find the difference between these two timestamps please help me

```
27-FEB-12 02.11.31.910000000 AM, 27-FEB-12 02.11.49.002000000 AM
```

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 2):

Subtract them.  The result will be an `INTERVAL` data type representing, in this case, 17.092 seconds.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select to_timestamp( '27-FEB-12 02.11.31.910000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM') -
  2         to_timestamp( '27-FEB-12 02.11.49.002000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM')
  3*   from dual
SQL> /

TO_TIMESTAMP('27-FEB-1202.11.31.910000000AM','DD-MON-RRHH.MI.SS.FF9AM')-TO_
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-000000000 00:00:17.092000000
```

Answer (score 1):

For more control over how your output is displayed, you can use `EXTRACT`:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM (x.ts2 - x.ts1)) ,'fm00')                     hours
  2  ,      TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (x.ts2 - x.ts1)) ,'fm00')                     minutes
  3  ,      TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (x.ts2 - x.ts1)) ,'fm00.' || RPAD('0',9,'0')) seconds
  4  FROM (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('27-FEB-12 02.11.31.910000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM') ts1
  5        ,      TO_TIMESTAMP('27-FEB-12 02.11.49.002000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM') ts2
  6        FROM   DUAL) x
  7  ;

HOU MIN SECONDS
--- --- -------------
00  00  17.092000000

SQL>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm.