# subtract timestamp in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, timestamp

I want to get the different between two `TIMPSTAMP` in a function.

Input function: n_LECT_DATE_TIME_START  and   n_LECT_DATE_TIME_END.

Output function: (n_LECT_DATE_TIME_END -  n_LECT_DATE_TIME_START) in hours. (***number?***)

This code not work... I got 2 errors:

`Error(5,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored` and

`Error(5,13): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`.

```
FUNCTION   check_time(n_LECT_DATE_TIME_START AF_LECTURE.LECT_DATE_TIME_START%TYPE,
                      n_LECT_DATE_TIME_END AF_LECTURE.LECT_DATE_TIME_END%TYPE)
     RETURN number IS 
    BEGIN
    RETURN  n_LECT_DATE_TIME_END -  n_LECT_DATE_TIME_START;
END check_time;
```

AF_LECTURE.LECT_DATE_TIME_END and AF_LECTURE.LECT_DATE_TIME_START type is TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Difference of two timestamps is INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, not NUMBER. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618722/2890093).

Comment: @Kombajn zbożowy thanks. It's work. but how I call this types in JAVA? I tried "Types.TIMESTAMP" but I got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract days, multiply that by 24, and then extract hours and add that # to the (days*24) to get the number of hours between 2 timestamps.

This is an illustration of the # of hours between 7/22/14 at midnight and right now:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33167/0

```
select extract(day from timediff) * 24 + extract(hour from timediff) as hours_diff
  from (select systimestamp - to_timestamp('2014-07-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as timediff
          from dual)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to get also  a negative time... how?

Comment: Should be able to reverse the 2 timestamps, ie. to_timestamp('2014-07-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - systimestamp , following the above example (rather than the other way around)