# How can I find the duration of time in UNIX format between two dates in TIMESTAMP format?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle

In Oracle, how can I find find the duration of time in UNIX format between two dates in TIMESTAMP format?

```
START_DATE                END_DATE                   DURATION
    "2014-08-07 10:02:39.0",  "2014-08-07 10:07:08.0"    ???UNIX FORMAT
```

Comment: Duration cannot be in UNIX format

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/

Comment: Since Unix timestamps are just seconds since the epoch, duration is the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do the following in PHP.

```
$start_date = strtotime("2014-08-07 10:02:39.0");
$end_date = strtotime("2014-08-07 10:07:08.0");

$duration = $end_date - $start_date;
```

Unix "format" or Unix Timestamp is all the seconds leading from 1970-01-01, till the date it's pointing at. So all the seconds from `1970-01-01 to 2014-08-07 10:02:39.0` for e.g.;

`strtotime();` is a [PHP Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

That converts "virtually" any given string representation of a date, into a Unix Timestamp.

After you've converted your dates into Unix Timestamps and subtracted them accordingly, what you have left with are the seconds that have passed between `2014-08-07 10:02:39.0` and `2014-08-07 10:07:08.0`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know, but I have no way to use PHP

Comment: Then howcome you use the PHP tag ?