# How do I find transactions that are less than 10 minutes apart using timestamps in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have only gone so far:

```
select timestamp, trans, Count(trans)  
From(
    Select to_char(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) as timestamp,SOURCE_MSISDN||DEST_MSISDN||AMOUNT as trans
    From ADMDBMC.TRANSACTION_CASH
    WHERE TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) > = '1-sep-2014' AND TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) < '2-sep-2014'
    and STATUS_DESCRIPTION='SUCCESS'
    ) 

group by timestamp,trans
Having count(trans)>1
order by count(trans) desc
```

Comment: Query is ok whats its result?

Comment: Why are you applying the `to_date()` function on a column that is (apparently) already a `date` (or `timestamp`). All that you are doing is to convert the  `date` to a `varchar` and then convert it back to a `date`. That's totally useless.

Comment: I will correct that

@Zeshan I want the query to only give me results of transaction less than 10 minutes apart.

Comment: did you mean from 1-sep-2014 00:00 to 1-sep-2014 00:10? @Kax

Comment: You want to include any transaction in your result provided you can also find another transaction - no more that 10 minutes apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by truncating your timestamp on the nearest multiple of 10 minutes: you could replace `to_char(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) as timestamp` with `regexp_replace(to_char(CREATED_TIMESTAMP, 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), '.$', '0')` and I think your group by would then be ok.

**EDIT** : the previous solution was only working if the 2 transactions were part of the same multiple of 10 minutes. Here is a better one:

```
Select *
From
(
    Select CREATED_TIMESTAMP,
           SOURCE_MSISDN||DEST_MSISDN||AMOUNT as trans,
           lag(CREATED_TIMESTAMP, 1, null) over (partition by SOURCE_MSISDN||DEST_MSISDN||AMOUNT order by CREATED_TIMESTAMP) as PREVIOUS_TIMESTAMP
    From ADMDBMC.TRANSACTION_CASH
    Where TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) >= '1-sep-2014'
      And TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) < '2-sep-2014'
      And STATUS_DESCRIPTION='SUCCESS'
) 
where CREATED_TIMESTAMP <= PREVIOUS_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
```

The `lag` analytical function allows to get for every row the timestamp of preceeding row of the same group identified by the concatenation of `SOURCE_MSISDN` / `DEST_MSISDN` / `AMOUNT`. Then once we have this, we just have to check the difference.

Comment: I want to check the time in between time stamps.. if the time is less than 10 min then return the result.. so for example if first time time stamp is 1:03 AM and next time stamp is 1:12 AM then then that transaction should appear in the resuts

Answer (score 0):

Emmanuels way would return false negative for example if one transaction occured at 11:49 and second at 11:52

You could use LEAD or LAG aggregate function with window option to get timestamp of a older row then current and calculate [difference between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds) 
or COUNT(*) with window, for example:

`select * FROM (
Select 
    to_char(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) as timestamp,SOURCE_MSISDN||DEST_MSISDN||AMOUNT as trans
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE_MSISDN||DEST_MSISDN||AMOUNT ORDER BY CREATED_TIMESTAMP RANGE NUMTODSINTERVAL(600,'SECOND') PRECEDING) L_OF_TRANS
    From ADMDBMC.TRANSACTION_CASH
    WHERE TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) > = '1-sep-2014' AND TO_date(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) < '2-sep-2014'
    and STATUS_DESCRIPTION='SUCCESS'
) WHERE L_OF_TRANS > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [to_dsinterval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions192.htm) function.  Subtracting timestamps gives intervals, so you can compare timestamps using to_dsinterval.  For example:

```
select *
from my_table x
where x.timestamp1 - x.timestamp2 < to_dsinterval ('00 00:10:00');
```

In this example, timestamp1 would be the more recent timestamp.

Comment: If it satisfies your question, feel free to accept the answer, thanks Kax.