# how to convert mysql TIMESTAMPDIFF to oraclesql query

Tags: sql, oracle

TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, pk.consprtydate, rs.consprtydate)

wanted the difference of hours from two dates and extract the hours in oracle sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write mysql TIMESTAMPDIFF function in Oracle sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150837/how-to-write-mysql-timestampdiff-function-in-oracle-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can easily achieve it by substracting two date fields as following:

```
Date2 - Date1  -- returns number of days between dates
(Date2 - Date1)/24 -- returns number of days between dates
MONTHS_BETWEEN(Date1, Date2) -- returns number of months between dates
```

Cheers!!

Comment: ?? `exp` and `exp/24` cannot give the same "number of days between dates"...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the datatype. IF they are of Oracle type TIMESTAMP, then follow the methods [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds)

If they are of type date, then - as said by Tejash- simple subtraction gives the difference in days that you would then need to round to hours. (integer portion will be days = 24 hours, and the decimal portion will be in fractions of a day)

e.g.) to round down to the integer number of hours without a fractional part:

(days * 24 hours, plus the fraction of a day * 86400 seconds in a day / 3600 seconds in an hour)

```
SELECT   trunc(date1 - date2) * 24    +  trunc((mod (date1-date2,1) * 86400) / 3600) 
FROM DUAL
```