# Calculating the difference between two timestamps

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, intervals

I am trying to calculate the difference between to timestamps, but the output only returns the difference in days, but not time:

```
DECLARE
   a INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(00);
  TT DATE := TO_DATE('15-Nov-2015 10:00 am', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi am');
  TS DATE := TO_DATE('17-Nov-2015 12:12 am',  'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi am');

BEGIN


   --Compute interval and assign to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND variable

   a := TO_TIMESTAMP(TS,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi am')
        - TO_TIMESTAMP(TT,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi am');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
END;
```

### This returns

+02 00:00:00

Comment: You have tagged your question MySQL, yet you are using Oracle syntax.  What database are you really using?

Comment: Oracle database, sorry

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2015-11-15 10:00:00');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2015-11-17 12:12:25'));
echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';
```

This code will output

The above code will output:

2 days total

0 years

0 months

2 days

2 hours

12 minutes

25 seconds

You can further calculate the time difference in minutes and seconds

Comment: Santosh Jagtap, what language is that? PHP? I am using Oracle pl/sql

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   a INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(0);

BEGIN

   --Compute interval and assign to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND variable

   a := TO_TIMESTAMP('17:00',' hh24:mi ')
        - TO_TIMESTAMP('08:00',' hh24:mi ');
     --   - TO_TIMESTAMP('20-SEP-2015 10:59 pm','dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi am');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(a, 5, 6));
END;
```

This is the correct solution! Thanks for the attempted help!