# SQL timestamp comparison and arithmetics

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to query and join two tables from database by connecting to an MS SQL DB server, where the Timestamps from two tables are equal (at 'minute' or "hour" precision).

```
SELECT
      M.TIME,
      M.ERRORCODE,
      A.TIME,
      A.ASSAYNAME
FROM
      MESSAGES M, ASSAYS A
WHERE
      M.TIME = A.TIME
```

The problem is the TIME for both tables are like this format "12/07/2015 12:00:12 AM". How am I able to ask SQL only compare the time within more relaxed time frame, say at minute or at hour level.

For example 
Precision at minute level
"12/07/2015 12:00:12 AM" will be considered equal to "12/07/2015 12:00:59 AM"

Precision at hour level
"12/07/2015 12:00:12 AM" will be considered equal to "12/07/2015 12:45:59 AM"

Precision at 10 minutes
"12/07/2015 12:00:12 AM" will be considered equal to "12/07/2015 12:09:59 AM"

I think another way to ask this question is "Are there ways to evaluate two timestamps by arithmetic" like M.TIME - A.TIME < 10 minutes

Comment: which db you are using

Comment: I guess this topic would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds

Comment: What are the SQL data types of the columns?

Comment: The DB is Microsoft SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can see whether the two datetime values are within 10 minutes of each other like this:

```
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, M.TIME, A.TIME)) < 10
```

Or within 10 hours of each other like this:

```
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, M.TIME, A.TIME)) < 10
```

Comment: For "within 10 hours of each other like this:
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, M.TIME, A.TIME)) < 10". Do you mean DATEDIFF(hour, M.TIME, A.TIME)

Comment: I tried this, but it complained DATEDIFF is not recognizable identifier. I guess it is because that I am connecting to a Microsoft SQL server, which I forgot to mention. I apologize.

Comment: I'm certain `DATEDIFF` works on Microsoft SQL Server.  Try this for example: `SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '5/22/2016', '5/23/2016')`.

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you to reconsider your intentions when trying to join two tables on a date_time column type, but if you must...

(SQL Server based examples)

You simply need to cast both columns to a common format before comparing.

```
SELECT
      M.TIME,
      M.ERRORCODE,
      A.TIME,
      A.ASSAYNAME
FROM  MESSAGES M, ASSAYS A
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, M.TIME, 101) = SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR, A.TIME, 20)
```

Use DATEDIFF or DATEADD if you want to compare if a value falls into a range.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but both TIME values from table A and table M are in the same format. I was asking about how to do the comparison at different precision level though.

Comment: @ju no Ju, they are the same TYPE but format is not the same as TYPE. The function CONVERT will format the date-time values to the format of your choice (say, one with no milliseconds), and it returns a value of TYPE Varchar(), then is the resulting varchars (with no milliseconds) used in the comparison.