# Difference between 2 times in sec in Pl/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need some help to identify difference between 2 times in sec

variable :

`current_time` : this is current time

`check_begin_time` : in YYYYMMDDHH24MMSS format

I need to check the difference i.e. `current time  - check_begin_time`  in secs

Thanks.

Comment: Any attempts on your own?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating difference between two timestamps in Oracle in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As difference of two `DATE` datatype values in Oracle represents number of **days** between them, you have to multiply it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day) and 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour) and 60 (as there are 60 seconds in a minute).

So:

(setting date format, just to know *what is what*; you don't have to do that)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

I presume your value is stored as a string (according to date format you posted; though, it is wrong - minutes are `MI`, not `MM`) so first convert it to a `DATE` datatype value, and then do the calculation:

```
SQL> select sysdate now,
  2    (sysdate - to_date('20220614090500', 'yyyymmddhh24miss')) * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds
  3  from dual;

NOW                    SECONDS
------------------- ----------
14.06.2022 09:09:54        294

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (END_DT - START_DT) * 60 * 60 * 24 FROM MY_TABLE;    -- Seconds
SELECT (END_DT - START_DT) * 60 * 24 FROM MY_TABLE;         -- Minutes
SELECT (END_DT - START_DT) * 24 FROM MY_TABLE;              -- Hours
```

To get more info refer to this link: [Date Difference](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/back-to-basics-date-difference-in-seconds-oracle/)