# I need to subtract the current timestamp from the most recent timestamp that was used in a table using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables: `Employees` with the employee info and `Download` with the timestamp that the application was downloaded.

I have to subtract the current timestamp from the most recent download time stamp. I figured out the most recent download and also know how to get the current timestamp. I just can't figure out how to get the difference.

The query I used for getting the most recent download is:

```
SELECT MAX(srvr_timestamp) from jaherna42.download; --***dB.table
```

The query I used for getting the current timestamp is:

```
SELECT current_timestamp from dual;
```

Comment: To subtract one timestamp or date from another you need to use... Subtraction. See [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating difference between two timestamps in Oracle in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617962/calculating-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-oracle-in-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract one from the other in the same query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(srvr_timestamp) - current_timestamp AS diff
from   jaherna42.download;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qLx6l59k)

Comment: Thank you it worked. I had it backwards because I thought you would have to subtract the max(srvr_timestamp) from the current_timestamp, since current time is "bigger" than the other times.