# Find difference between two dates Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to get the difference between two date times. The issue I am facing is that I have to convert the date from the table, to a usable date. i.e. 7841433540 converts to 09/10/14 09:19:00. My sql to return those values is:

`SELECT  ddt.tochar(ENC_START_DDT,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS') "Admit",
        TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS') "Today"
from CCDBA.PATIENT where CCDBA.PATIENT.PAT_SEQ = '101067048';`

Now I thought I could...

```
SELECT  ddt.tochar(ENC_START_DDT,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS')-TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

from CCDBA.PATIENT where CCDBA.PATIENT.PAT_SEQ = '101067048';

But that returns:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:
*Action:

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the information at this page help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql

Comment: I had seen that, but the answer below worked, I had forgotten to convert to a date. I'll get there, a little at a time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot subtract strings and expect the database to understand them as dates.  So, convert them to dates:

```
select (to_date(ddt.tochar(ENC_START_DDT,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS') -
        sysdate) as diff
from CCDBA.PATIENT
where CCDBA.PATIENT.PAT_SEQ = '101067048';
```

Comment: This worked, returned a negative value, so I just swapped them.Thank you very much!