# Oracle SQL - DateDiff Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting a 'Missing Expression' error. Do you see the problem? It's probably something stupid.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.CODE = 'CONTACT_CLIENT' THEN (@DATEDIFF('DD',a.LASTMODIFIED,w.DATE_OPEN)) END AS "MET"
  FROM WORKORD w
  INNER JOIN WORKDET wd on wd.TTNUM = w.SEQ_ID
  INNER JOIN ACTIONS a on a.SEQ_ID = wd.ACTION
```

Comment: Problem is, this is not a a Syntax for Oracle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 4):

`datediff` isn't a function in Oracle.  You also wouldn't prefix a function name with the `@` sign.

Assuming that `a.lastModified` and `w.date_open` are both of type `date`, you can simply subtract them to get a difference in days.

```
CASE WHEN a.CODE = 'CONTACT_CLIENT' 
     THEN a.lastModified - w.date_open
 END
```

If you want an integer number of days (since `date` values always include a time component, subtracting two dates will frequently result in a non-integer number of days), throw in a `trunc` or a `round` depending on what you want to do.

Of course, I'm not sure why you don't have an `ELSE` in your `CASE` statement or why you have identifiers with underscores between words (`date_open`) and identifiers without underscores (`lastModified`).  But that doesn't appear to be part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Are you refering the [`@DATEDIFF`](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/column_conversion_functions011.htm) conversion function from Oracle GoldenGate ?

This will *not* work in the Oracle RDBMS. There, you will have to use the *minus* operator:

```
a.LASTMODIFIED - w.DATE_OPEN
```

The result will be in fractional days. If you only need the number of *days*, you will have to trucate the result. Giving:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.CODE = 'CONTACT_CLIENT' THEN
                 TRUNC(a.LASTMODIFIED - w.DATE_OPEN)
       END AS "MET"
...
```

See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_date_arithmetic.htm for a simple introduction to date arithmetics using Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@DATEDIFF` is not a function in Oracle. Try `trunc(a.LASTMODIFIED - w.DATE_OPEN)`.