# Finding difference between date fields of different formats

Tags: sql, oracle, date

My query returns the two fields in the select line.  I need to find the difference in HH:MI:SS between the two fields.  I keep getting errors when I try DIFF or even TO_DATE.  The format for each field is different and the field are in different tables.  ALARM_GENERATION_DT is in the PHM_INTERACTION_PERS table and the CALL_START is in the PHM_OUTBOUND table.

The formats for each field are as follows:

```
ALARM_GENERATION_DT        mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss AM/PM
CALL_START                 yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT  p.alarm_generation_dt, o.call_start
FROM phm_interaction_pers p, phm_outbound o
WHERE p.otb_id = o.record_id
AND o.call_start like '2015-03%';
```

Comment: What data types are the columns? Different format either implies at least one is a string, or one is a date and the other a timestamp (neither of which have any intrinsic format).

Comment: or both are strings with a different format.

Comment: call_start from the phm_outbound table is varchar2 (25 byte) and alarm_generation_dt from phm_interaction_pers is DATE, data default = systimestamp

Comment: **Never**, ever store dates as `varchar` - the problem you have right now stems directly from this bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

You'll just need to get your varchar2 date into a proper date format in order to do 'date math'.