# Joining 2 tables to calculate the time difference

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a couple of **seperate** event tables.
For a given id we would like to know the time difference between 2 events.
Now, there can be several of the same events for a given id, we are only interested in the "next" event.

Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f724/6/0

**Schema**

```
create table event_a (
  timestmp timestamp(3),
  id       varchar2(50)
);

create table event_b (
  timestmp timestamp(3),
  id       varchar2(50)
);

insert into event_a values (to_timestamp('2015-05-12 10:22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'x');
insert into event_b values (to_timestamp('2015-05-12 10:22:05', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'x');
insert into event_a values (to_timestamp('2015-05-12 10:22:08', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'x');
insert into event_b values (to_timestamp('2015-05-12 10:22:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'x');
```

**Query**

This is the query I came up with, but it seems to me to be a little too complex. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

This query also takes a long time to run if there is a lot of data in these tables.

```
select a.id, nvl((extract(day from (b.timestmp - a.timestmp))   * 86400
                 + extract(hour from (b.timestmp - a.timestmp))   * 3600 
                 + extract(minute from (b.timestmp - a.timestmp)) * 60   
                 + extract(second from (b.timestmp - a.timestmp)) ), 0) as duration_in_sec
from event_a a
join event_b b on a.id = b.id and b.timestmp = (
  select min(timestmp)
  from event_b
  where id = a.id
  and timestmp >= a.timestmp
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Not really Christian, I know how to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps, my question is more about the joining of these 2 tables to find the 2 timestamps to compare.

Comment: Why are you extracting days, hours, minutes and seconds separately, if you're only interested in "duration in sec"? You can do datetime arithmetic on Oracle, so you can just do `(b.timestmp - a.timestmp) * 86400`. As for the performance, look at the execution plan. Guessing doesn't really get you anywhere.

Comment: Are you not better off using the DATEDIFF function as it would give you the difference in seconds without having to resort to picking apart the dates. DATEDIFF(s, b.timestmp, a.timestmp)

Comment: Fair enough it did say possible, however the link does show a better way to do a datetime difference.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get the minimum time for b for an id but what about a? Is that max or min?

Comment: @Christian: it takes the time from a and then finds the lowest timestamp with the same id for b. The query on itself works, you can try it in sqlfiddle.

Comment: ok just checking you're after two results for a

Comment: @Luaan: This returns "+05 00:00:00.000000" instead of a numeric value. Perhaps this works for dates but not for timestamps?

Comment: @Tom DATEDIFF isn't an Oracle function

Comment: Are there any indexes on your real tables?

Comment: @Alex, yes there are, and they can help. I'm just not sure if my query is optimal.

Comment: Aaah, of course, my bad. So annoying. You could of course do the multiplication and then use `extract(day)`, but that's even uglier.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should be faster as it does not have self-join subquery:

```
select id, extract(day from (d)) * 86400 + extract(hour from (d)) * 3600 
         + extract(minute from (d)) * 60  + extract(second from (d)) duration
  from (
    select a.id, b.timestmp - a.timestmp d,
        row_number() over (partition by a.id, a.timestmp order by b.timestmp) rn
      from event_a a 
      join event_b b on a.id = b.id and a.timestmp <= b.timestmp
      order by a.timestmp)
  where rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f724/31)

Comment: That does indeed seem better! One thing though, I also need to partition on id, otherwise if a different id has an event on the same time, this query would only return 1 result. Updated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/875a5/1/0

Comment: Yes, I corrected my answer, not corrected SQLFiddle,

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and see if it works / performs better:

```
Select a.id, 86400 * (min(b.timestmp) - a.timestmp) diff
From event_a a
Join event_b b on a.id = b.id and b.timestmp >= a.timestmp
Group by a.id, a.timestmp
```

If this doesn't work for you then you can pretty much do your old query but using Group by:

```
Select a.id, nvl((extract(day from (min(b.timestmp) - a.timestmp))   * 86400
                 + extract(hour from (min(b.timestmp) - a.timestmp))   * 3600 
                 + extract(minute from (min(b.timestmp) - a.timestmp)) * 60   
                 + extract(second from (min(b.timestmp) - a.timestmp)) ), 0) as duration_in_sec
From event_a a
Join event_b b on a.id = b.id and b.timestmp >= a.timestmp
Group by a.id, a.timestmp
```

Comment: That also needs `and b.timestmp >= a.timestmp` in the join (and the OP's extraction to seconds, not multiplying by 24, since they are timestamps not dates). Then it works for the sample data at least.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole you're quite correct. Updated to reflect this

Comment: Yes Christian, that does seem better, it works using the "old" time difference. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I wasn't sure as I don't have Oracle, just seen someone saying the top should work but SQL Fiddle didn't like it so thought I'd post the second just in case. The Group By method should be more efficient for you hopefully.

Comment: Hmm, it definately should be more efficient, the explain plan is also a lot less complex with only 2x"table access" and a "hash join" vs 4x"table access" and 3x"hash joins". The only thing is, on the actual tables, this takes 143 seconds where my old solution only takes 105 seconds.

Comment: Do they use your indexes when it runs? It's a bit odd as I'd have expected it to run faster. Are your indexes covering indexes?

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamps of event_a and event_b **always** alternate then you can use:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f724/36)

```
WITH times AS (
  SELECT id, timestmp, 1 AS event_type FROM event_a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, timestmp, 2 AS event_type FROM event_b
  ORDER BY 1,2,3
),
timediffs AS (
  SELECT id,
         timestmp - LAG( timestmp ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestmp ASC, event_type ASC ) AS d,
         event_type
  FROM   times
)
SELECT id,
       extract(day from (d)) * 86400
        + extract(hour from (d)) * 3600 
        + extract(minute from (d)) * 60
        + extract(second from (d)) AS duration
FROM   timediffs
WHERE  event_type = 2;
```

Comment: Unfortunalely, I cannot be sure that they alternate.