# Get diff of time Oracle

Tags: oracle, time, diff

I have the next idea :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('14:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') - MIN(TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'HH24:MI:SS')) AS MINFECHA
  FROM ARCHIVO2
  WHERE DIA='LUNES';
```

I want to get the difference between the 2 fields that should be something like

```
00:46:00
```

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: You've removed a large chunk of important DATE data like day/month/year.  If you're only using hours/minutes/seconds, you'll never be able to differentiate between 36 hours and 12 hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: The fact is that for example an employee normally starts working at 14:00:00 but if the employee is late at work at 14:02:00 I want to be able to make the time diff that in this case it will be 00:02:00 (2 minutes late)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add/subtract dates and times when they're in character strings. To accomplish what you're trying to do you need to convert the character strings to DATE values, perform the necessary calculations, and then convert the result back to a character string:

```
WITH DATE_DATA AS
  (SELECT DIA,
          DATETIME,
          TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' ' || '14:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS BASE_TIME
     FROM ARCHIVO2)
SELECT DIA,
       DATETIME,
       BASE_TIME,
       (DATETIME - BASE_TIME) * 1440 AS MINUTES_LATE
  FROM DATE_DATA;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81de4/8)

Best of luck.