# Oracle - How to check entered date is greater than 9 months

Tags: oracle, validation, date

Need to check whether the employee has crossed the 9 months or not from his joining date.

Comment: Please include sample table data and any query you have already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating sample data as:

```
    create table employee(id number,hire_date date);
    insert into employee values(1,'12-APR-2017');
    insert into employee values(2,'18-Oct-2017');
    insert into employee values(3,'01-Jan-2018');

    select id,hire_date, case when months_between(sysdate,hire_date) > 9 then 'Crossed' else 'Not-Crossed'  end is_crossed from employee;
```

The output will be:

```
ID  HIRE_DATE   IS_CROSSED
1   12-APR-17   Crossed
2   18-OCT-17   Not-Crossed
3   01-JAN-18   Not-Crossed
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT to_char(TO_DATE(joindt,'DD/MM/RRRR')) < add_months(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),-9) 
FROM PYEMPMAS

Thanks guys. I got a solution..