# How to subtract two dateTime field containing dateTime in ISO format and get the result in hours?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to subtract two dateTime field containing dateTime in ISO format and get the result in hours?

I have tried subtracting two date fields but it has just subtracted date and not taken time into consideration

```
to_number(
 TRUNC(to_timestamp(T1.attribute_2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'))-
 TRUNC(to_timestamp(T2.attribute_2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'))
)
```

Date 1 2019-04-26 10:00pm
Date 2 2019-04-26 8:00pm
Expected Outcome: Date1- Date 2 = 2(in hrs)
Actual Outcome: Date1- Date 2 should give 0

Comment: What is the _datatype_ of `T1.attribute_2`? You're missing the point if you don't specify the datatypes. In your example your subtracting the same value from itself so the result will always be zero

Comment: It is the date in ISO format

Comment: That is not a data type. Please take some time to understand what a datatype is. This is particularly important in a database

Comment: Two date fields are getting subtracted from two different tables having date in ISO format

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the different tables bit. You need to specify the datatype. Is it `varchar2`?

Comment: There are a few suggestions here, but if you are working in databases, particularly with dates, you really need to understand the concept of datatypes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the hours into consideration, then don't truncate the values!  `TRUNC()` removes the time component.

For hours, multiply the difference by 24:

```
(to_timestamp(T1.attribute_2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')-
 to_timestamp(T2.attribute_2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')
) * 24
```