# How I can substract one timestamp from another in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

How can I subtract one timestamp from another in Oracle?

for example I have:

```
timestamp_1 = 2021-06-25 08:18:17,207141  
timestamp_2 = 2021-06-24 17:41:06,787111
```

how I can take a different between?

I need a diff in seconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: The term to search for in the future when Googling about things like this is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply subtract the two values from each other

```sql
SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-06-25 08:18:17,207141', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF')
       - TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-06-24 17:41:06,787111', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF')
  FROM DUAL;


+00 14:37:10.420030
```

Comment: @SQL_Python_DataScience - just keep clear in your mind that when you subtract dates/times from each other, what you get is not a date or a time of day, but an _elapsed time_.  So the '14:37:01.420030' result in Ej Egyed's answer is not 2:37:01 PM, but 14 hours, 37 minutes, 1 second and 420030 nanoseconds.  You may say 'well, that's obvious', but you'd be surprised at how many people somehow miss that point.

Comment: that is not anwering the question of how many seconds are between those dates